# Car doesnt recognize my music downloaded with my own python app

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I created a little python app and included "pytube" a youtube library. The only purpose is to give the app a link to a youtube video and download it as mp3, everything is working fine and I can listen to the song on my computer.
When I put the music on an USB Stick and plug it into my car, nothing happens and my car says the stick has no media.
When I use some other mp3 files I have (not from my tool) the car recognizes the files and plays music.
This is the code that I use to download the music, does anyone have an idea why my car doesnt recognize the mp3 file?

Update: The car is a Hyundai i10

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in ('Exit', None):
            break           # exit button clicked

    if event == 'Download':

        yTVideo =  YouTube(pyperclip.paste())
        destination = _path
        print('Downloading '+ yTVideo.title + ' to : '+ destination)
        window.refresh()
        video = yTVideo.streams.filter(only_audio = True).first()

        out_file = video.download(output_path=destination)

        base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
        new_file = base + '.mp3'
        os.rename(out_file, new_file)

        print('Download Completed!')
```

- tried on different computers/laptops -> works fine
- tried differenct USB sticks -> same result, didnt work

Comment: Please provide more detail about the car. A number of things are possible, but I'd gamble the most likely is the car just expects the usb to be formatted differently.

Comment: The USB works fine with other mp3 songs

Comment: @WeedWizard probably the mp3 songs has another encoding that the MP3 player of your car does not recognize - (*I had a similar problem, but, in my case it was because the MP3 songs has images attached to them - I used BrainMusic "or something like that for edit manually the MP3 file metadata and image cover"*). Try to comparte the properties of a working and a non-working MP3 file and see any differences. [edit] your question and add those details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the MP3 ID3 Metadata Tags?

I encountered a similar problem while trying to play MP3 songs on an old MP3-Player.

The problem was that the MP3-Player didn't recognize the MP3 files because of missing ID3 Tags. After manually adding some metadata it worked again.

Maybe compare the metadata of the MP3's that work with the ones that don't and see which ID3 Tags are missing?

Its a shot in the dark but I hope it might help.