# Mp3 files that downloaded using pytube cannot edit mp3 tags properly

Tags: python, mp3, pytube

I want to use pytube to download music, but the Mp3 files that downloaded with it cannot display ID3 tags(album, artist, etc.). I used eyed3, MoviePy and Mp3tag, however, they did not solve my problem. And I cannot listen these music on speaker, too.

The file format that downloaded using `yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()` is mp4, I want to use mp3 file. The method I found on the web is to change the file extension directly.

```py
from pytube import YouTube
import os

yt = YouTube(input('Url of the video...'))
print('Got', yt. title)

path = "C:/Users/USER/Music"
video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
out_file = video.download(output_path=path)
base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
new_file = base + '.mp3' # Change.mp4 to .mp3
os.rename(out_file, new_file)

print(yt. title, "downloaded")
```

But when I happily started to set the album and artist information, I found that they could not be modified. I tried eyed3, but found that only a few times the label can be added normally, and if I write a program to change the label after downloading, it will not work at all.

```py
artist = input('Artist...')
album = input('Album...')

file = eyed3. load(new_file)
file.initTag(); # Actually I don't know what this did
file.tag.artist = artist
file.tag.album = album
file.tag.track_num = i + 1 # I used a loap to set track num
file.tag.save()
```

I tried the app Mp3tag. It shows `ERROR: MP3 header parse error` on the program interface (see this: [How to fix ERROR: MP3 header parse error](https://community.mp3tag.de/t/how-to-fix-error-mp3-header-parse-error/58511), but it can be edited. However, the edited tags cannot be displayed in File Explorer, and edited files cannot be played with . It is worth noting that the files that have not been modified with Mp3tag can still be played on the computer, but when I use the speaker with USB disk, it cannot play. (see this: [Car doesnt recognize my music downloaded with my own python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73659760/car-doesnt-recognize-my-music-downloaded-with-my-own-python-app))

PS: I have tried MoviePy to turn the file to mp3, but it return `KeyError: 'video_fps'`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the extension from `.mp4` to `.mp3` only tricks your music player into thinking it is an mp3, but it is infact still an mp4 file.

Your speaker probably is not smart enough to read these mp4 files, and the mp3 tag library cannot change tags on the mp4 file since it is a different file type.

You would need an extra step to convert the mp4 to mp3 file properly. A solution can be via [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) as suggested by another stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081352/how-to-convert-mp4-to-mp3-using-python).

Comment: I tried MoviePy, but it seems cannot turn the mp4 file without video into mp3. It return `KeyError: 'video_fps'`.

Comment: @ClayHsu you need an mp4 with the video as well for `MoviePy`, not an audio only mp4. This means that you have to download the video **without** `only_audio=True` and then convert that to mp3. It will take more space during the initial mp4 step, but you can delete that file after the conversation anyway.

Comment: Gosh, I know I can do that, but it takes a lot of time, Internet and memories. And my environment doesn't allow these. Do you have any other way to just capture the audio and convert it to mp3 smoothly? Thank:)

Comment: You can also look into `ffmpeg`. Here's a [link](https://superuser.com/questions/332347/how-can-i-convert-mp4-video-to-mp3-audio-with-ffmpeg) that could be useful. To call it inside python program, you would have to call it with `os.system()`. For more details on that, you can check out [executing shell commands with python](https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-python/)

Comment: If it can help, you can find an example at https://github.com/starnutoditopo/mp4_to_mp3 : it converts MP4 files to MP3, using MoviePy . Have a look!